# Flyway migration after jpa tables have been created

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, database-migration, flyway

I'm using flyway database migration tool with a spring boot jpa project. When I run the server first flyway wants to migrate sqls, but tables have not created yet. In this case flyway returns an error which like

`Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateSqlException: 
Migration V1__countries_and_states.sql failed
SQL State  : 42S02
Error Code : 1146
Message    : Table 'wallet.country' doesn't exist
Location   : db/migration/V1__countries_and_states.sql (/root/IdeaProjects/service/target/classes/db/migration/V1__countries_and_states.sql)
Line       : 1`

I configured application.properties file with these options:

- spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
- spring.flyway.enabled=true
- spring.flyway.clean-on-validation-error=true
- spring.flyway.init-on-migrate=true

I want that my migration will have been successfully  done.

Comment: You probably should have the JPA provider output the DDL script(s) to files instead of having it create tables &c. on the fly at runtime. Then you can use those DDL scripts with flyway. It's not a good practice to have a normal application execute DDL anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be used configuration properties like: `flyway.out-of-order = true`. It says flyway works after hibernate/jpa has been created/updated tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your first migration must create the tables!

Read this tutorial: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/api

Comment: Thank you **Simon Martinelli** but I wanted migrate flyway sqls after hibernate autocreate tables. I think it is impossible with flyway

Comment: Plus that's not a good idea! The best is to let hibernate create the SQL DDL file and then improve this and use as the first migration.